# C++ call C# CLR function SpinWaitInternal

Tags: c#, c++, .net

I have a c++ application where I want to busy spin like [SpinWaitInternal in NET](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/thread.cs,02b14e4e04277120,references).

This is the relevant code part in the CLR:

```
/* wait for a length of time proportial to 'iterations'.  Each iteration is should
   only take a few machine instructions.  Calling this API is preferable to coding
   a explict busy loop because the hardware can be informed that it is busy waiting. */

 [System.Security.SecurityCritical]  // auto-generated
 [MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall),
  HostProtection(Synchronization=true,ExternalThreading=true),
  ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.Success),
  ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)]
 private static extern void SpinWaitInternal(int iterations);
```

In the comment MS states that they use this API "because the hardware can be informed that it is busy waiting".

At first I thought to import the specific function from mscorlib.dll - but no exports can be found with dependency walker. So that's a NET thing.

How can I achieve the same with VC++ 2017?

Comment: FWIW, that method is called by `Thread.SpinWait(int)` which is publicly accessible.

Comment: It is assembly code inside the CLR.  For x86/x64 processors it executes REP NOP (aka PAUSE).  For ARM it does nothing.  In C++ you'd favor [YieldProcessor()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687419(v=vs.85).aspx).  Don't overlook that SpinWait explicitly yields the thread when it has to spin too often.